# How not to encode values in XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml, decode, encode

I have a xml document that I am editing in a C# script.

1. I am using .load to read the doc in.
2. .SelectSingleNode to find the node to edit.
3. setting the .value of the attribute I want to set.
4. Using .Save

Here is the rub....

I am saving a SQL statement for the Salesforce inteface in the .value. When you use the .save it encodes (> into &gt) the string. I can't have this as Salesforce does know how to encode/decode so it has to be the specific string I set to. What is the best way to save the doc without encoding. I guess I could read the xml doc in and parse to a filestream editing the string when I get to it but it seems cumbersome....

Comment: Can you edit a code sample into your question, to make sure everyone is on the same page?

Comment: There is a reason for that encoding: the document would be invalid XML otherwise. Please show a sample.

Comment: Use element instead of attribute. Use CDATA section. Inside CDATA section characters like `>` etc. are stored without encoding.

Answer (score 1):

An XML is - technically spoken - a string. In other words: a chain of characters.

What makes the difference are the *mark-ups*. You need *special characters* to distinguish them from the rest.

Three characters are absolutely sacrosanct: <, > and &

The first two build the mark-ups and the last one is the escape character, telling a reading instance: Look, this is a special character!

If you want to use these characters *within* XML you *must* escape them with `&lt;` `&gt;` and `&amp;`. The rest depends on the given encoding. UTF8 handles a different set of characters than UTF16 - and there are many more...

This means: There is no way around encoding/escaping such characters *within* XML.

If you want nothing more than to deal with the XML *as string* this is very easy: Your XmlDocument has `OuterXML`, which is a `string` returning property. It will deliver the whole XML as string.

But keep in mind, that your XML will break, if you use not encoded special characters in the wrong places...

#### EDIT

Actually there is a way around (as pointed out by Alexander Petrov: a CDATA section. The question is: How is the reciever *reading* your data? If everything goes the *normal* way, encodings are no problem as any reader will re-encode your data before showing it to the human reader.